# Transformations in Eigen::Affine3f

Tags: translation, transformation, linear-algebra, eigen

I am not too familiar with Eigen library and I am stuck at this piece of code

```
motor1_to_motor2 =
          Translation3f(BigApeLeg::distanceJoint1ToJoint3(),0,0)
        * AngleAxisf(M_PI_2, Vector3f::UnitX())
        * AngleAxisf(M_PI_2, Vector3f::UnitY());
```

motor1_to_motor2 is Eigen::Affine3f
Big::ApeLeg::distance... must return a float number

But my issue is what is Translation3f and what is AngleAxisf. What do they do? And what do they return?

I am familiar with some basic transformations. I would really appreciate if someone can give me any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its name stands, a [Translation3f](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Translation.html) represents a 3D translation using floats. An AngleAxisf represents a 3D rotation of given angle around given axis. Both are class constructors, not functions.

motor1_to_motor2 is thus an affine transformation applying a rotation around Y followed by a rotation around X and finally a translation along the X axis.

This [doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialGeometry.html) should give you a good introduction on space transformations in Eigen.